# Does opening multiple file handlers slow down write times?

Tags: python, file

In python is the process of opening a file handler slow compared to the actual write time?

One large file, one file handler

```
import marshal
bigDataStructure = [[1000000.0 for j in range(1000000)] for i in range(1000000)]
f = open('bigFile' , 'w')
marshal.dump(bigDataStructure , f)
f.close()
```

multiple smaller files, multiple file handlers

```
for i , row in enumerate(bigDataStructure):
 f = open(str(i) , 'w'):
 marshal.dump(row , f)
 f.close()
```

Comment: These do two different things, so comparing the time between them doesn't seem very useful. What are you _really_ trying to accomplish?

Comment: @sarnold writing a neural network to file. If I write one neuron at a time I don't need any new data structures. If I merge all the neurons together, then I need to merge A LOT of data into a new data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention running out of memory if you merge them all -- that's a *lot* of neurons. (At least, in my experience, several hundred neurons were sufficient for the toy programs we wrote in my CS courses.)

You probably don't want to be creating 100,000 separate files to store 100,000 separate neurons -- and certainly not 1,000,000 files to store 1,000,000 neurons. The IO overhead of directory lookups, file open, read, close, and *small* amounts of IO will drastically weigh on loading and saving with non-trivial amounts of neurons.

Of course, if you're thinking 50 or 100 neurons, then it'll go quickly no matter what, and perhaps the simplest implementation is called for.

But if this were mine, I'd look hard at trying to build good data-structures for the neurons: perhaps all your neurons in a given level can be described by an integer to select neuron type and an array of integers or doubles to describe per-neuron characteristics, and a list of these level descriptions could be easily written to separate files or a single file, whichever is easier.

If your neurons change types within a level, or aren't fully connected between levels, you might find some [sparse matrix storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) designs useful for a larger data structure that can describe all the neurons at once.

Maybe the *real* question should be "how do I improve the storage of my neurons?"

**Update**

I think even 10,000 neurons justifies making a "combined" storage format. I just created 10,000 tiny files, dropped my caches to test a cold-start, and then re-read each one individually. It took 14.6 seconds to read in 10,000 files. It took only .1 seconds to read in a single file containing the same data as the 10,000 files.

If your network starts "cold" once a year or so, maybe it won't matter much. But if your network starts cold a dozen times per day, you might grow to resent the simpler storage format.

Comment: There are around 10,000 neurons, but each makes clique connections. I should be able to get away with only 10,000 files.

Comment: Average run times for 250,000 neurons is around 200 hours but I can only request 60 hours a time on a shared cluster. So I have to load about two or three times every 200 hours.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize time was at such a premium. _Definitely_ use a single file and work to optimize read and write times to the single file. Another hour of your time when you can't otherwise be computing might help you reduce the time you need on the shared cluster.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the multiple-filehandler-approach may be slower, because there will be performed a write to the file system for every `close()` operation. If you're writing small chunks at a time, this is slower (because you may be writing less bytes than a sector size) than letting the lower levels (OS, file system, block device) handle buffering and writing, ensuring you don't waste lots of writes smaller than sector size.

Comment: I was worried about this. But I might run out of memory if I merge all the data prior to writing it.